# BlockingCollection auto executes my functions when I attempt to add them to list

Tags: c#, execute, blockingcollection

```
            var tasks0 = new BlockingCollection<object>(new ConcurrentQueue<object>());
            tasks0.Add(Fetch(APCounter));
            tasks0.Add(Decode(APCounter));
            tasks0.Add(ALURes(APCounter));
            tasks0.Add(Memory(APCounter));
            tasks0.Add(WriteB(APCounter));


            var tasks1 = new BlockingCollection<object>(new ConcurrentQueue<object>());
            tasks1.Add(Fetch(APCounter+1));
            tasks1.Add(Decode(APCounter + 1));
            tasks1.Add(ALURes(APCounter + 1));
            tasks1.Add(Memory(APCounter + 1));
            tasks1.Add(WriteB(APCounter + 1));
```

I don't want it execute the functions being added now. I'll do that manually later using the business logic. !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you'll need to store a list of Delegates, or something similar, to do what you want.  You are executing those functions and then storing the result in a blocking collection.  The first thing that you need to do is change the generic type on the blocking collection to:

```
//add tasks
//if the functions return a common object other than "object" then adjust this accordingly
var tasks0 = new BlockingCollection<Func<object>>();//defaults to using a ConcurrentQueue
tasks0.Add(()=>Fetch(APCounter));
tasks0.Add(()=>Decode(APCounter));
tasks0.Add(()=>ALURes(APCounter));
tasks0.Add(()=>Memory(APCounter));
tasks0.Add()=>(WriteB(APCounter));
```

Then to actually execute the functions:

```
//run tasks
object firstResult = tasks0.Take()();
object secondResult = tasks0.Take()();
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question you want to store in your queues lists of functions, that will be called later. If this is the case, what you need is:

```
tasks0.Add(() => Fetch(APCounter)); 
tasks0.Add(() => Decode(APCounter));
```

etc. - because

```
tasks0.Add(Fetch(APCounter));
```

adds the result of a call to `Fetch(APCounter)`, whereas

```
tasks0.Add(() => Fetch(APCounter));
```

adds a delegate calling `Fetch(APCounter)`

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding methods to the list if you are trying to do it. You are calling methods like `Fetch(APCounter)` and then adding the result of that method to the `BlockingCollection`.

Try creating delegates and adding the delegates to the collection instead.

```
public delegate FetchFunction(int apCounter);
tasks0.Add(FetchFunction(APCounter);

// or using lambda expressions
tasks0.Add(() => Fetch(APCounter));
```

Comment: tasks0.Add(() => Fetch(APCounter);
It says: Argument Type Lambada isn't assignable to parameter of type object @Arif Mert Akçakaya